# Determine whether a number is in a GP or not

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is there a quick way to find out whether a number is a part of a Geometric series?

Given the starting number of the series(a) and its ratio(r).

Comment: What do you mean by part of the series? Do you mean it is a term in the summation? If so think about the geometric sequence.

Comment: Try thinking about logarithms base $r$.

Answer (score 1):

All numbers, $N$, in the sequence can be represented as:

$$N=ar^{n}, \qquad n\in \mathbb{N}\cup \{0\}$$

In order to find out if an arbitrary number is in the sequence, assuming $r \in \mathbb{R}^{+}\setminus \{1\}$, we can divide by $a$ first, which for a number in the sequence will give us:

$$N/a=r^{n}$$

And then if we take the logarithm base $r$, we have:

$$\log_{r}\left(\frac{N}{a}\right) = n, \qquad n\in \mathbb{N}$$

So we will get an integer, if and only if our number was in the geometric progression.

Comment: Be careful about the case where $r\leq 0$ or $r=1$ as $\log_r$ is not defined.

Comment: @JMoravitz Yes, this is true. Let me edit my answer

Comment: The case where $r=1$ is trivial, $N$ would be a member of the GP iff $N=a$, as is the case where $r=0$ in which case $N$ is a member iff $N=a$ or $N=0$.  For $r=-1$, similarly, $N$ is a member iff $N=a$ or $N=-a$.  The difficult remaining case is when $r<0, r\neq -1$.  Approach similarly to your solution, but break into $N/a$ as positive/negative and the exponent as even/odd.